# Cancel currently running function/goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm using [gin-gonic](https://gin-gonic.github.io/gin/) as HTTP handler. I want to prerender some graphical resources after my users make `POST` request. For this, I put a middleware that assign a function (with a timer inside) to a `map[string]func()` and call this function directly after assignation.

The problem is, when the user make two subsequent request, the function is called twice.

Is there any way to clear function ref and/or his currently running call like a `clearInterval` or `clearTimeout` in Javascript ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; whatever function you've scheduled to run as a goroutine needs to either return or call `runtime.Goexit`.

If you're looking for a way to build cancellation into your worker, Go provides a primitive to handle that, which is already part of any HTTP request - contexts. Check out these articles from the Go blog:

[Concurrency Patterns: Context](https://blog.golang.org/context)

[Pipelines and cancellation](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your rendering function is calling into a library, so you don't have control over the code where the bulk of the time is spent. If you do have such control, just pass a channel into the goroutine, periodically check if the channel is closed, and just `return` from the goroutine if that happens.

But actually I would recommend a different, and simpler, solution: keep track (in a `map`) of the file names (or hashes) of the files that are currently being processed, and check that map before launching a second one.

Comment: I want to close the first rendering, because the user `POST` will affect the content of the rendering. So wait to start the second is useless, i want to replace the first start by the second.